# Android making basic home screen launcher application

Tags: android, launcher, homescreen

I want to make my application home screen launcher. Is there any **basic** example shows how to make a home screen launcher application in Android?

Comment: There is a [sample](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Home/index.html) in the SDK samples

Comment: @RaghavSood Thank you :) I have to improve myself about using Android SDK.

Comment: @halilkaya  what u tried ?